# Replace specific word in a string

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am finding difficulty to change the word of a string to fixed one. Below are contents of the string

```
 CREATE TABLE "USER1"."TEST_TAB"
   (    "O_ID" CHAR(15),
        "CREATED_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
        "EVENT_ID" NUMBER,
        "LOD" BLOB,
        "TOPIC" VARCHAR2(765),
        "SCHEMA_ID" VARCHAR2(36),
        "RECORD_ID" CHAR(15),
         CONSTRAINT "R_PKCONDUIT_MESSAGE" PRIMARY KEY ("O_ID", "TOPIC", "EVENT_ID", "CREATED_DATE") ENABLE
   ) O INDEX COMPRESS 2 PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255  NOLOGGING
  TABLESPACE "D01"
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 PCTTHRESHOLD 50
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION
  NOCACHE LOGGING
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT))
  PARTITION BY HASH ("O_ID")
 (PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE01"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD01"(
  TABLESPACE "D01" )
  TABLESPACE "D01" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE02"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD02"(
  TABLESPACE "D02" )
  TABLESPACE "D02" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE03"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD03"(
  TABLESPACE "D03" )
  TABLESPACE "D03" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE04"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD04"(
  TABLESPACE "D04" )
  TABLESPACE "D04" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE05"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD05"(
  TABLESPACE "D05" )
  TABLESPACE "D05" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE06"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD06"(
  TABLESPACE "D06" )
  TABLESPACE "D06"
/
```

trying to change TABLESPACE "D01" .... TABLESPACE "D06" to fixed name of TABLESPACE "COPY_TBS"

```
string.replace('TABLESPACE \"D[0-9][0-9]+\"','TABLESPACE COPY_TBS')
```

Seems not working. Is there any way to change this string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unlike other answer, there is an easier way to do it. Assign your data to a variable:

```
a = '''CREATE TABLE "USER1"."TEST_TAB"
   (    "O_ID" CHAR(15),
        "CREATED_DATE" DATE DEFAULT SYSDATE,
        "EVENT_ID" NUMBER,
        "LOD" BLOB,
        "TOPIC" VARCHAR2(765),
        "SCHEMA_ID" VARCHAR2(36),
        "RECORD_ID" CHAR(15),
         CONSTRAINT "R_PKCONDUIT_MESSAGE" PRIMARY KEY ("O_ID", "TOPIC", "EVENT_ID", "CREATED_DATE") ENABLE
   ) O INDEX COMPRESS 2 PCTFREE 10 INITRANS 2 MAXTRANS 255  NOLOGGING
  TABLESPACE "D01"
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
 PCTTHRESHOLD 50
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE (
  DISABLE STORAGE IN ROW CHUNK 8192 RETENTION
  NOCACHE LOGGING
  STORAGE(
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT))
  PARTITION BY HASH ("O_ID")
 (PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE01"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD01"(
  TABLESPACE "D01" )
  TABLESPACE "D01" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE02"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD02"(
  TABLESPACE "D02" )
  TABLESPACE "D02" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE03"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD03"(
  TABLESPACE "D03" )
  TABLESPACE "D03" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE04"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD04"(
  TABLESPACE "D04" )
  TABLESPACE "D04" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE05"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD05"(
  TABLESPACE "D05" )
  TABLESPACE "D05" ,
 PARTITION "CONDUIT_MESSAGE06"
 LOB ("LOD") STORE AS BASICFILE "LOD06"(
  TABLESPACE "D06" )
  TABLESPACE "D06"'''
```

And then use a loop to replace:

```
for i in range(1,7):
    a = a.replace('TABLESPACE "D0'+str(i)+'"','TABLESPACE COPY_TBS')
```

You can test it here online:
https://repl.it/@blackskull12/DisfiguredMemorableStructs

#### Edit:

As it will not work with numbers higher than `10` then your loop can be like (it will work with numbers less than 100):

```
for i in range(1,20):
    a = a.replace('TABLESPACE "D'+str(i).zfill(2)+'"','TABLESPACE COPY_TBS')
```

Comment: This works so long as there is no `D10`, or `D100`, etc.  In that case, you'd probably want to stick with a regex approach.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen There is also a solution. Just give me a min.

Answer (score 5):

You should use `re.sub`:

```
string = re.sub(r"TABLESPACE \"D[0-9]+\"", "TABLESPACE COPY_TBS", string)
```

`string.replace` does not work with regular expressions.

### Demo

Also, I changed the pattern to match the table space name to `D[0-9]+`, assuming that you want `D` followed by any number of digits.  If you really want to restrict to only two digits, then use `D[0-9]{2}`.